# Creating "polymorphic" controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im working on adding voting to my app (like in Stackoveflow). I have two models Questions and Answers so i want to be able to vote for both of them. I see two ways to manage voting for different type of models:

1. Add concern for models, controllers and routes.
2. Add votes_controller that can handle voting for any model that has votable.

I`d like to use second way to solve my problem. But to use controller I will should pass two parameters to controller, like: votable_type: model-name, votable-id: object.id, and my route will look like: vote_up_vote_path, vote_down_vote_path.

Is there a way to use routes like: vote_up_path(answer); vote_down_path(question)?

And by passing object "vote_up_path **(answer)**" i want to be able to get it in controller

P.S. I`m not able to use gems. Gems provide logic for models, I'm already have this logic.

I found the solution. So at first we need to generate Votes controller.

```
$rg controller Votes
```

Than we add routes:

```
resource :vote, only: [:vote_up, :vote_down, :unvote] do
    patch :vote_up, on: :member
    patch :vote_down, on: :member
    patch :unvote, on: :member
end
```

And add in votes_helper.rb:

```
module VotesHelper
  def  vote_up_path(votable)
    {controller: "votes", action: "vote_up",
     votable_id: votable.id, votable_type: votable.class}
  end

  def  vote_down_path(votable)
    {controller: "votes", action: "vote_down",
     votable_id: votable.id, votable_type: votable.class}
  end

  def  unvote_path(votable)
    {controller: "votes", action: "unvote",
     votable_id: votable.id, votable_type: votable.class}
  end
end
```

Than we should add tests and complete our methods. In controller we can use this method to find our votable:

```
private

  def set_votable
    klass = params[:votable_type].to_s.capitalize.constantize
    @votable = klass.find(params[:votable_id])
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Highly recommend this gem to handle upvote/downvote:

[Acts as votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable)

Comment: Its good, but i can't use gems. Because its training task, so i should complete this story independently.

Comment: Oh I see. Then why not using parameters? If I were you, I would just use one path `vote_path` and get three parameters: value(0, 1, -1), votable_type and votable_id. I believe the gem did something similar.

Comment: May be it meets the required task, but I'm talking about creating controller that don't represents resource. Is it an acceptable practice?

Comment: take a look at the acts as votable gem lib files, understand it and you'll see how you can do what you asked since you are not allowed to use gems. It's using a polymorphic association @Alexandr

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense. Just as @ollaollu said, learning from what the gem did will help you a lot.

Comment: This gem is about logic and models. I already have my voting logic. Now i need to add actions in controller and i'v done it. I can make concern with this actions and include it in my question and answer controllers. But i want to use independent controller, i think concern is not right there.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this; the first is to use superclassed controllers, the second is to use an individual controller with a polymorphic model.

I'll detail both:

---

**Superclassing**

You can set a method in a "super" controller, which will be inherited by the `answers` and `questions` controllers respectively. This is kind of lame because it means you're sending requests to the `answers` or `questions` controllers (which is against the [DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :answers, :questions do
   match :vote, via: [:post, :delete], on: :member
end

#app/controllers/votes_controller.rb
class VotesController < ApplicationController
   def vote
       if request.post?
          # Upvote
       elsif request.delete?
          # Downvote
       end
   end
end

#app/controllers/answers_controller.rb
class AnswersController < VotesController
   # Your controller as normal
end
```

... Even better ...

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def vote
      ...
   end
end

#app/controllers/answers_controller.rb
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
   ....
end
```

This will allow you send the following:

```
<%= link_to "Upvote", answers_vote_path(@answer), method: :post %>
<%= link_to "Downvote", questions_vote_path(@question), method: :delete %>
```

-

The important factor here is that you need to ensure your vote logic is correct in the backend, which you'll then be able to use the `vote` method in the `VotesController` to get it working.

---

**Polymorphic Model**

Perhaps the simplest way will be to use a [polymorphic model](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations):

```
#app/models/vote.rb
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :voteable, polymorphic: true
end

#app/models/answer.rb
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :votes, as: :voteable
end

#app/models/vote.rb
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :votes, as: :voteable
end
```

This will allow you to do the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources vote, only: [] do
   match ":voteable_type/:voteable_id", action: :vote, via: [:post,:delete], on: :collection #-> url.com/vote/answer/3
end

#app/controllers/votes_controller.rb
class VotesController < ApplicationController
   def vote
     if request.post?
       @vote = Vote.create vote_params
     elsif request.delete?
       @vote = Vote.destroy vote_params
     end
   end

   private

   def vote_params
     params.permit(:voteable_id, :voteable_type)
   end
end
```

This would allow you to use the following:

```
<%= link_to "Vote", votes_path(:answer, @answer.id) %>
```